# Cannot build realm database in iOS with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

This is Realm database for react-native https://github.com/realm/realm-js

I have done for android app, but when I configured for iOS, I could not find this file "libRealmNode.dylib" in my project. So my question is: How to generate this file?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is trying to load this file? If you are using `rnpm`, it should be adding `libRealmReact.a` to your xcodeproj, not the filename you have listed.